# python web3 account sign_message with nonce

Tags: web3js, python, message

I want to sign message for login dapp,

The message is like "Welcome !" and have Nonce.
How can I using sign_message function with nonce?

In the Metamask show like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood, it's just one message that you need to sign.

Some background on how it works. Let's use [Nansen](https://www.nansen.ai/) as an example as it's the closest to the one on your screenshot.

When you click "Sign in with Wallet" (e.g. MetaMask), the app server generates a message with a time to live & a nonce. Here's what the message looks like in the MetaMask UI:

[image: MetaMask sign-in]

And here's what's actually sent to you from the server:

```
app.nansen.ai wants you to sign in with your Ethereum account:\n0x9729187D9E8Bbefa8295F39f5634cA454dd9d294\n\nBy signing this transaction you are allowing Nansen to see the following: your wallet address.\n\nURI: https://app.nansen.ai\nVersion: 1\nChain ID: 1\nNonce: BELEGLDkqN5\nIssued At: 2024-01-15T09:19:11.000Z
```

So, you need to sign the entirety of this message as one with your private key:

```
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
from web3 import Web3

private_key = '1e5a89614d79cab1e39a45f5b116498a38d373ba117a05b35df397f42d7a0c94'

# The message you received from Nansen
message = "app.nansen.ai wants you to sign in with your Ethereum account:\n0x9729187D9E8Bbefa8295F39f5634cA454dd9d294\n\nBy signing this transaction you are allowing Nansen to see the following: your wallet address.\n\nURI: https://app.nansen.ai\nVersion: 1\nChain ID: 1\nNonce: BELEGLDkqN5\nIssued At: 2024-01-15T09:19:11.000Z"

# Encode the message
encoded_message = encode_defunct(text=str(message))

# Sign the message with your private key
signed_message = Web3().eth.account.sign_message(encoded_message, private_key=private_key)

print("Signature:", signed_message.signature.hex())
```

Once you get the signature, you need to post it back to the app server within the time to live period so that you get signed in.

Comment: Thank you for your apply, In my message have "\\n", so I change "\n" and work well. but, How can I get Nonce??

Comment: Issued At and Nonce just can get in the app server?

Comment: I searched all the Network sections through Chrome developer tools, but I couldn't find a network that receives time and nonce.